# Bloco if/else não funcionando no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, if

Estou começando no JavaScript e estou criando um bot de WhatsApp no Node.js e qualquer bloco `if` que coloco não funciona e sempre vai pro `else`.

Funciona assim:

- Recebe a mensagem;
- Faz uma query no banco de dados SQLite e verifica se o número de quem enviou a mensagem está no banco de dados e aumenta uma variável (`cnt`);
- Um bloco `if` verifica se a variável `cnt` é maior que `0`, se não, significa que o número não está no banco e o adiciona.

O problema, é que o bloco `if` não funciona, sempre retornando `else`.

Já tentei usar `if (+cnt > +0)`, tentei usar um array, colocando todos os números nele e usar um `arr.includes(message.author)`, mas obtenho o mesmo erro, nada que eu coloque no `if` funciona.

Será que eu tô esquecendo de alguma coisa? Tem a ver com a database?

```js
function start(client) {
  client.onMessage(async message => {
    db.serialize(function() {
      var cnt = 0
      db.each(`SELECT phone as phone, xp as xp, admin as admin, lastmsg as lastmsg, msgcount as msgcount FROM users`, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message); 
        }
        if (Object.is(row.phone, message.author)) {
          cnt++;
        }
        console.log(message.author + " - " + row.phone + " - " + cnt)
      })
      if (+cnt > +0) {
        console.log(`Usuario ${message.author} já existe na database.`);
      }
      else 
      {
        db.serialize(function() {
          db.run(`INSERT INTO users (phone,xp,admin,lastmsg,msgcount) VALUES ("${message.author}",0,0,0,0)`);
          console.log(`Usuário ${message.author} adicionado a database.`);
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: creio que `db.each` seja uma funcao assincrona, logo esse `if/else` abaixo deveria estar dentro da funcao de _callback_.

Comment: `if (+cnt > +0)` - não precisa desses `+` (essa é uma forma de converter strings para números, mas tanto `cnt` quanto `0` já são números, então esse `+` é realmente desnecessário aí)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certamente o método db.each(...) é uma função assíncrona, já que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados e precisa que o mesmo responda, o if/else teria que estar dentro dessa função de callback ou você pode usar o [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) do JavaScript, muito comum no NodeJS.

Exemplo com o if/else dentro da função de callback:

```
function start(client) {
  client.onMessage(async message => {
    db.serialize(function () {
    var cnt = 0
    db.each(`SELECT phone as phone, xp as xp, admin as admin, lastmsg as lastmsg, msgcount as msgcount FROM users`, (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    if (Object.is(row.phone, message.author)) {
      cnt++;
    }

    if (cnt > 0) {
      console.log(`Usuario ${message.author} já existe na database.`);
    } else {
      addContato(message.author);
    }

    console.log(message.author + " - " + row.phone + " - " + cnt)
   });
  });
 });
}

function addContato(autor) {
 db.serialize(function () {
  db.run(`INSERT INTO users (phone,xp,admin,lastmsg,msgcount) VALUES ("${autor}",0,0,0,0)`);
  console.log(`Usuário ${autor} adicionado a database.`);
 });
}
```